# Crash with the method query of android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm try to verify if in my db android a user is registered or not. I have this class that create db and have the method for verify if a user is registred:

```
    public boolean isRegistered(String username, String password) {
          boolean in = false;
          Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_USER, new String[] {USERNAME,PASSWORD},
            USERNAME + " = '" + username + "' AND " + PASSWORD + "= '" + password+"'",
            null, null, null, null);

          if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                  in=true;
          if(!cursor.isClosed())
                  cursor.close();
   return in;
   }
```

The application crash when run this method. Why? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can pass simple query to data base and get the user count from that. like this way.

```
 public static SQLiteDatabase Objdatabase;

 SQLiteStatement stmtSelectRec=Objdatabase.compileStatement("Select count(0) from table where username='abc' and password='123'");  

 int countnumber=(int)stmtSelectRec.simpleQueryForLong();

 if(countnumber)>0?True:false.
```

Comment: Egual. I don't see the database in my phone but when i add a new user the function that put a new user in database don't crash...but this function crash!